# React checkbox - Onchange checkbox, coming undefined for 1st time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React checkbox - Onchange ouput as undefined for 1st click(time). After that showing valid true or false output.I googled this issue but not solving the problem.

Please help, What i'm doing wrong here.

I defined checked as **false** in the State:

```
  constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
         formFields: {
            checked: false,
          },
        };
      }
```

Handling the checkbox:

```
handleCheckBox = (e) => {
    this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked });
    console.log("checked", this.state.checked);
    // this.setState({ checked: !this.state.formFields.checked });
    // console.log("checked", this.state.formFields.checked);
  };
```

destructuring:

```
const { ...formFields } = this.state;
```

In the form checkbox input as follows:

```
<input
     type="checkbox"
     checked={formFields.checked}
     onChange={this.handleCheckBox}
 />
```

On check for first time the output as follows:
[image: output]

Comment: You are logging ```this.state.checked``` in your example. You should be logging out ```this.state.formFields.checked```. I think it's just a typo. So you've not defined ```this.state.checked``` in your state initially

Comment: @DevStormUK, yes I check both.if you see in the code i commented **this.state.formFields.checked**. Both giving the same output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `setState` works asynchronously. To get the behaviour that you want pass the console.log as a callback in the setState function:

```
this.setState(
     { checked: !this.state.checked }, 
     () => console.log(this.state.checked)
);
```

The callback will be called after the state has been updated. By calling console.log() outside of the callback, javascript will run the console.log before the state has updated.

This is because no matter what, the current call stack has to be cleared before any async calls are made.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Call_stack#:~:text=A%20call%20stack%20is%20a,from%20within%20that%20function%2C%20etc.

Comment: i'm accepting your answer. Still warning is coming. Thanks

Comment: First, you are destructuring incorrectly const { ...formFields } = this.state; change it to const { formFields } = this.state. Second, formFields is not updated. Remove formFields and just change it to { checked: false } in the constructor. And then checked={this.state.checked}